# DDD Monolith eshop architecture based on multiple BoundedContexts Question

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, cqs

I´m creating my first eshop / CMS based on DDD / CQS concepts. I want to create application using BoundedContexts separtion as modular monolith at the first stage and maybe latter extract some BC as MiniServices.

I Want to ensure that I´m going the raight way, so I prepare Architecture diagram.

**Diagram:**

[image]

As you can see on diagram I Have currenty 3 bounded contexts, Catalog, Ordering, ShoppingCart. Each of them are fully separed and inside of them I´m using CQS for better code organization.

Each bounded context have own ApplicationServices (Commands / Queries), Domain logic may have saparated DB or in this case I´m using only one shared DB whith custom Scheme.

I want to help with Shopping Cart (Read/Write model), because I´m not sure with this.

This bahaviour I´m expecting from CART:

1. User can add Products from Catalog to his Shopping cart session
2. User can modify paroduct quantity in cart (0-x)
3. User can delete product from cart
4. User can see product name, price, quantity, code in shopping cart datail view
5. User can enter and appply copon code for discount
6. User can enter / choose Shipping / Payment method
7. User can see total cost, total cost with TAX
8. User can enter aditional delivery / invoice information
9. User can checkout cart => Will create new order 
   *10. User will be informed about product price change in catalog (system must warring user about inconsistency between product price and shopping cart price) before checkout.

I decided to create custom layer / project "BFF.ForMonolith" where I can use public intefaces from BoundedContext (ex. ICatalogReadAppService, ICatalogCommandAppService). This project will create API gateway / facade for various clients).

In this project I will be able to create read model which will contain data from multiple BC. Ex. return ShoppingCartViewDto with aditional product info from catalog BC. 
Or checkout cart and create order with actual product price consistency validation.

If I decide to crate new TaxCalculation BC I use this project to supply info about product price and tax category from other BCs.

**Scalability:**

Because I Will work only with abstraction, I suppose that I will capable of migrate any Bounded Context as separed Service with custom API in future.

**Read Model possibility:**

- If I will have only one DB. Read model can by also created by plain SQL with .NET DAPPER library with cross DB schema joins.
- Because I use commands I Can in future create and record events in Event Store - careate read model from event projections

**My intentions are:**

- Create simple DDD modular monolith
- Possiblity to convert module-s / BC to service / mini(or)micro-service if scalling will be necessary
- Possiblity to use one or multiple DB
- Reuse modules between projects

**My questions are:**

- I this solution clear for you ?
- Can by do it better ?
- Is my concept/thoughts about BFF (to create read model) valid?

Comment: you dont need cart at all. its the same as order.

Comment: you dont need to seperate read and write. catalogue is allways read, order is (almost) always write

Comment: I can recommend this free ebook for you. It was very helpful for me. https://aka.ms/microservicesebook